# Iframe in Azure Webb

Tags: azure, iframe, azure-web-app-service, iframe-app, frameset-iframe

I have a website in Azure App Service. There is an Iframe with this

`<iframe id='iframe2' class="embed-responsive" src="http://52.173.85.103:8069/" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe>`

But all other element work but just the iframe not working
[Here](https://visualizadordashboards.azurewebsites.net/pagina/test)

I think that maybe Azure restrict the SRC, because with domain page it´s working.

Answer (score 0):

Azure doesn't impose any restrictions with regards to how HTML elements work. I checked your site and the iframe appears to be working correctly. Should it happen again, I would check Network traffic using your browser developer tools to check what responses you're getting from http://52.173.85.103:8069. I would also use the DNS name instead of the IP address should the dependency site ever change IPs.